# How to stop Visual Studio from removing event handlers when deleting winform controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am in the process of redesigning a desktop application with 120+ winforms.  As you can expect, this takes quite a bit of time.  One thing that slows me down is when I am swapping out old controls for new ones.  If I delete the old control, all of the event handlers are removed, so I have to rename the new control and then go add them back in.

This behavior makes absolute sense but I was wondering if I could turn it off and if so, how?  It would make my life so much easier if I only had to work in the designer, instead of switching back and forth with the code.  Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: If you change the view of the Property window from Properties to Events (click the lightening bolt) you can select from qualifying existing events from the list top wire them up.

Comment: This is a great help, I still wish I could turn off the auto-delete but this little nugget of information at least keeps me from going back and forth so much.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of replacing the control why not just update it (assuming they are of the same type). You could easily use reflection to copy the properties from on control to the other.

Comment: I'd just copy all the form code to a notepad file until I was done swapping and then paste it back in, fixing any wrong signatures VS lights up.

Answer (score 1):

It "unhooks" the handler (removes the `Handles....` portion) so that you cant eventually end up with multiple handlers.  Since the code block remains, you can wire a control to existing event blocks from the IDE:

**Switch To Events View**

From the Property Pane/Window, click the Lightening bolt to show events:

[image]

**Select Existing Event**

Methods which have a signature matching that of the desired event (in this case, `sender As Object, e As EventArgs`) will show in the drop down for you to select from.

[image]

In this case, it includes `Form_Load` just because the signature matches.  New events handlers can be created from here by Double Clicking the event name.

If you select multiple controls on the Form designer/IDE, then create a new event (or select an existing one) the selected controls will be wired to a single handler.